# React router dom type error / FC{} | ReactNode is not assignable to type ReactNode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm new to typescript. I'm working on a project and using `react-router-dom`, and whenever I'm trying to create the elements in the App.tsx I get an error.

This is the code:

```
<Route path="landing-page" element={landingPage} />
```

Here is the error:

> Type 'FC<{}> | ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
> Type 'FC<{}>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2322)
> components.d.ts(52, 5): The expected type comes from property 'element' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'

For my components at first I gave them a type of `React.FC` but when I got this error I tried to change it to `React.ReactNode | React.FC` but still nothing is rendering on the page. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: can you please share code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: i'm just trying to make a nvigation in my app, added react-router-dom and followed the docs, but it's not working 
imported my components in the app.tsx and created routes for them but i get the error mentioned in the question
`<Route path="landing-page" element={landingPage}/ >`

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. You've just listed tags. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @MohamedAmineBenSalah this error is telling you that landingPage is actually either a Functional Component (FC) OR a ReactNode, when it is expected to only be a ReactNode. Without seeing your code we are unable to tell **why** it is coming up as a Functional Component.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this is my first question on stackoverflow sorry for the absence of specification and what an awesome community
i found the error it was a typo instead of element={<landingPage/>} i was typing it {landingPage}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Route` component's `element` prop takes ***only*** a `React.ReactNode` type. In other words, it takes JSX.

[Route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/route)

> ```
> declare function Route(
>   props: RouteProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouteProps {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   element?: React.ReactNode | null; <-- ReactNode or null
>   index?: boolean;
>   path?: string;
> }
> ```

Pass the `LandingPage` component as JSX instead of as a reference to a React component.

```
<Route path="landing-page" element={<LandingPage />} />
```

Answer (score 2):

For those trying to quickly wrap their heads around the new V6 [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/) API (as of June/2022), just change this:

```
    <Route path="landing-page" element={landingPage} />
```

into this:

```
    <Route path="landing-page" element={<landingPage\>} />
```

The `landingPage` element assignment should be `<landingPage/>` instead, which is a React Node.

Comment: No. `landingPage` is not the name of a component (component names are capitalized) and `<landingPage\>` is not valid JSX.