# Getting "Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'." when creating a React app with Vite

Tags: typescript, vite, react-typescript

I have created a React app with Typescript with npm create vite@latest. When I have done like this before everything have been working fine but when I did it today I get the errors:
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.

The page works fine in the browser without any errors though.

I'm using Visual studio code version: 1.81.1 and Typescript version 5.1.6.

These errors also shows up when I open previous projects that have been working fine in the past.

I have tried changing settings in tsconfig.json, for example moduleResolution: bundler --> node, but it did not help.

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import reactLogo from './assets/react.svg'
import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
import './App.css'

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <a href="https://vitejs.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={viteLogo} className="logo" alt="Vite logo" />
        </a>
        <a href="https://react.dev" target="_blank">
          <img src={reactLogo} className="logo react" alt="React logo" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h1>Vite + React</h1>
      <div className="card">
        <button onClick={() => setCount((count) => count + 1)}>
          count is {count}
        </button>
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to test HMR
        </p>
      </div>
      <p className="read-the-docs">
        Click on the Vite and React logos to learn more
      </p>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

[Image of code and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLWvX.png)

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72618998/react-router-dom-type-error-fc-reactnode-is-not-assignable-to-type-reactno?rq=2) could be the solution for you too. Try it!

Comment: I found no way to apply this solution to my problem. My theory is that it's got something to do with Typescript since i get the errors in my old project as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Solved this by clearing VS Codes cache: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/vscode-clear-cache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by [clearing VS Codes cache](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/vscode-clear-cache)

Comment: This solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 17):

Upgrade your "@types/react" in devDependencies to 18.2.25 as such:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/react": "18.2.25",
    ...
  },
```

also in my case, i had to add the same version to "overrides" too, while keeping react-dom 18.2.0

Comment: Well done. It had an immediate effect.

Answer (score 9):

Adding `"@types/react"` to the `"devDependencies"` in package.json using the same version as the react version used in the project and then running `npm i` helped me. If it can't resolve peer dependencies, try `npm i --legacy-peers-deps`.

Comment: it didn't solve the issue on my side :'(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, fixing my dependencies with `npm audit fix` somehow fixed all my errors.